# Fontawesome with important in a variable php

Tags: php, syntax, quotes

I need to create a shortcode with a simple line :

```
$ret = '<i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="content: "\f090" !important;"></i> Texte';
```

The tag !important is mandatory.
The problem comes from the syntax of php with ' and ". There are ' then " then " again and the !important is not applied.

Thank you to help me.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$ret = '<i class="fa fa-sign-in" style="content: \'\f090\' !important;"></i> Texte';
```